# Referencing items in enumerate

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

I'm trying to cross-reference items in an enumerate and I'd like the reference to be exactly the "(C1)-tag" in the enumerate.

```
\begin{enumerate}[(C1)]
\item For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $f_n$ is a $C^{1+\alpha}$ 
 diffeomorphism onto its image for some $\alpha\in(0,1]$, and 
 $f_n(0)=0$. \label{cdt:C1}
\item There is a $Df_n(0)$-invariant splitting 
 $V_n=E^u_n\oplus E^s_n$, i.e. 
 \begin{equation*}
    Df_n(0)E^\tau_n = E^\tau_{n+1},\quad\text{for}\,\,\tau =u,s.
 \end{equation*}\label{cdt:C2}
\end{enumerate}
```

However, when using `\ref{cdt:C1}` it only shows a "1". How can I make it take the whole "C1"?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: you don't say but I guess you are using the enumerate package, use enumitem instead which lets you specify the reference form as well as the item label form

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, I didn't know this existed. It works like magic.

Comment: @MathematicalMoose: Are you interested in a `C1` or `(C1)` as reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you omit the parentheses around the Cx numbers in a cross-reference. This, too, is easy to achieve with the help of the `enumitem` package.

[image]

Remark: If you do want parentheses around "C1" in the cross-reference, just omit the option `ref=C\arabic*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(C\arabic*),ref=C\arabic*]
\item \label{cdt:C1}
For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $f_n$ is a $C^{1+\alpha}$ diffeomorphism onto its image for some $\alpha\in(0,1]$ and $f_n(0)=0$. 
\item \label{cdt:C2}
There is a $Df_n(0)$-invariant splitting $V_n=E^u_n\oplus E^s_n$, i.e.,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:C2}
    Df_n(0)E^\tau_n = E^\tau_{n+1}\text{ for $\tau =u,s$.}
\end{equation}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent
See equation \eqref{eq:C2} in claim \ref{cdt:C2}.

\end{document}
```